# how to put a web link inside a popover?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, popover

I'm trying to put a link to access help as follows ...

```
... a class="help-button" data-rel=​"tooltip" data-trigger="hover" data-placement="right" data-content='Help...' title data-original-title="​Popover test">?').appendTo($('#title').parent());
```

but does not create the link, the popover work fine. Could anyone help me please!

Comment: Please post all of the relevant code or create a [bootply](http://bootply.com)

Comment: Thank Skelly, I posted this but dont work..and so I tried to post here a fragment ...but Miljan posted properly below.

Answer (score 0):

I've simply added HTML element inside `data-content`, like this:

```
data-content="Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus. <a href=''>HELP</a>"
```

and it works.

Here is [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/CegDv/1/)

Comment: Thanks Miljan, I tried just like but not work ... I am trying to insert a button with popover directly  in the browser console.


$('<a class=\"help-button" data-rel=​\"tooltip" data-trigger=\"hover" data-placement=\"right" data-content="<a href='#'>Help...</a>" title data-original-title=\"​Popover on hover">?</a>').appendTo($('#nome').parent());


The error mensage: "SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL" , just the data-content

Comment: Miljan, thanks one more time.. I'll try this... You are the guy!